# Softlayer API to get the target IP address

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have one softlayer replica setup, for Primary volume i can see Target IP address on UI (when i open volume details page) but for replica i cannot see the Target IP address. Can some please help me to find Target IP address for replica volume through softlayer API.

I was using 'SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getObject'service to get all the details about volume but it doesnot show Target IP address details.

I need a help to find out the API which can give all the datails about volume including Target IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getReplicationPartners` method to get the replica ID. Once you have that you can use `SoftLayer_Network_Storage/<replica_id>/getServiceResourceBackendIpAddress` to get the Target IP address.

```
ryan@tycho ~ » curl -s --user "$SOFTLAYER_USERNAME:$SOFTLAYER_API_KEY" "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/8744521/getReplicationPartners" | pmj
[
    {
        "accountId": 78003,
        "capacityGb": 20,
        "createDate": "2016-12-30T10:57:50-06:00",
        "guestId": null,
        "hardwareId": null,
        "hostId": null,
        "id": 18032161,
        "nasType": "ISCSI_REPLICANT",
        "serviceProviderId": 1,
        "serviceResourceName": "PerfStor Aggr aggr_staasdal0101_pc01",
        "storageTypeId": "8",
        "upgradableFlag": true,
        "username": "SL01SEL78003_3_REP_1"
    }
]

ryan@tycho ~ » curl -s --user "$SOFTLAYER_USERNAME:$SOFTLAYER_API_KEY" \
"https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/18032161/getServiceResourceBackendIpAddress"
"10.0.90.87"%
```